# change laravel createDirectory owner from root user to other user

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, server

on my ubuntu server I have a `web3` user and on my website with `laravel`
I have below code to create the directory

`Storage::disk('products')->makeDirectory($media_dist, 0755, true);`

and the owner of directory is `web3` but when It create the directory it has a `root` user

I want to know how it could be happend and have a `root` user.

how I could change that to create directory with owner of `web3`?

Comment: How do you serve your files? Webserver or `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I have a webserver and use ispconfig for config my website with nginx

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to Larvel directory

```
sudo chown web3:web3 /location_to_your_project/storage/

sudo chgrp -R web3 storage bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: "_but when It create the directory it has a root user_" The directory already has `root` as owner, that's not what OP wants

Comment: all my directories has a `web3` user as owner but when `laravel` create the directory the directory has `root` as owner but I want it has `web3` as owner

Comment: Answer Updated, please check

Comment: @Waqar I will let you know whether or not your update works, since I also want the Laravel storage function to create the directory as the current web server user, not as root.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create directory in storage folder, you can use "File" facade instead of "Storage". Do something like this:

```php
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
    //...

    $storage_path = storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
        'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images';
    if(!File::exists($storage_path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($storage_path, 0755, true, true);
    }
```

This piece of code working for me for Linux and Windows as well.
It will be better to make "web3" user as owner of "storage/..." just one time and be sure about later directories inside of it.

> sudo chown -R web3:web3 storage/

This will let the web3 user to work with logs and laravel caches as well, without permission errors.
So for every new directories you can work with them.

**NOTE** Don't change permission mode of any folder in laravel and don't use "chmod" command (especially 775 or even 777). It's not safe.

**Additional:**
Use this command to create shortcut as "public/storage/..." linked to "storage/public/app/..."

> php artisan storage:link